# Beautiful Soup error 'NoneType' object and if

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have problem with None element, I added if, to test for this, but it's still not working:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, "lxml")
element = soup.find(None, "div", class_='12345').find('a')

if element is not None:
    print "Your element is: " + element.text

else:
    print "No element"
```

Error:

```
    page = soup.find(None, "div", class_='12345').find('a')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: You are calling `.find()` on `soup.find(None, "div", class_='12345')`. You need to test that first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing **two** find calls:

```
element = soup.find(None, "div", class_='12345').find('a')
```

The **first** call fails, and it fails because you are looking for the wrong thing there, you are passing in `None` for the tagname, and `"div"` as the attribute mapping. That'll never work, so it *always* returns `None` and that object has no `.find` attribute.

You need to fix the call, and test if the `div` was found before trying to find a nested `a` tag:

```
element = None
parent = soup.find("div", class_='12345')
if parent is not None:
    element = parent.find('a')
```

I'd not make it that complicated however, I'd use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead, with the `soup.select_one()` method:

```
element = soup.select_one('div.12345 a')
if element is not None:
    # ...
```

The CSS selector will return the first `a` element that is a child element of a `div` tag with the class `12345`.